# Does Firebase capture Memory and CPU utilisation of the App?

Tags: firebase, firebase-performance

I analyze the memory and CPU utilization of my app from the terminal using the below commands

```
adb shell dumpsys cpuinfo
adb shell dumpsys meminfo com.company.packageName
```

The above approach is manual and looking to explore if FireBase addresses it ?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Performance does capture this information. More details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/console?platform=android#sessions)